# Admin Screen Edit Order Button Text

Tags: button, admin

Looking to change the text of the button in the Admin Order Edit screen. Instead of "Add Meta" I would like "Add Item Details"

tried looking on google and through the code, i'm lost.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: oh sorry...  this is for woocommerce when entering orders via the admin screen. not sure how to attach an image